# Integrate Jama library in Netbeans platform

Tags: java, netbeans, jama

I would like to integrate the Jama library into Netbeans (not just a single project). However, I get the message "`package Jama does not exist.`" I have done the following:

- I downloaded Jama's jar file.
- Then I went to `Tools`, `Libraries`, pressed the button `new library`.
- Put in the name of the library and hit `OK`.
- Then I hit the button "`Add JAR / Folder`" and chose the jar file.

What can this be? Unfortunately I only found descriptions of how to integrate libraries into individual projects.

Comment: right click `libraries` in the project list and then click `add`

Comment: Thank you, but when I right click on libraries I have only two possiblities:       1) Add Module Dependency...    2) Add new Library...

Comment: But no add JAR/File

Comment: Addendum: When I right-click on Properties, select Category: Libraries, the Platform Modules appear instead of Compile time Libraries. There is no button "Add JAR / Folder".

In addition, this window displays the message "Module JavaFX wrapper in platform requests the token org.openide.modules.jre.JavaFX but there are not known providers". However, the red Resolve button is not selectable. Is my problem related to this message?

Comment: I just tried it with a `Java Application` and `Web Application` and I am getting `Add JAR/File` option on right clicking `Libraries`. Try a clean installation of NetBeans.

Comment: I have installed NetBeans IDE 8.2 and JDK8. I have set the path with  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin; Other codes are running on the Gephi platform.    I suspect that it is on the Gephi platform

Comment: Maybe you can give a try to IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

You use the word "platform", so I'm assuming you are building an application based on the [NetBeans Platform](https://netbeans.org/features/platform/).

Whenever you want to use an external library in such an application it is generally (although not always, but it is the cleanest method) required to create a **library wrapper module** for your external jar. You essentially wrap that external jar in a NetBeans module. Then you include the newly created module in application.

Creating a library wrapper module is simple, but the method depends if you are using Ant or Maven:

- **Ant**: New project --> NetBeans Modules --> Library Wrapper Module

[image]

- **Maven**: Create an empty NetBeans module. Add your Jama library as a dependency, something like:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>gov.nist.math</groupId>
    <artifactId>jama</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

You also need to tell which packages your newly created module exposes to the rest of the world, but in your case it is likely to be everything, i.e. all packages in the jar.

Once you have wrapped your jar in a module then that functionality can be used from any other NetBeans Module as long as you create a dependency on your newly created module.

Note: If only one module in your application will actually directly interact with Jama (i.e. use its classes), then you do not need a library wrapper module. Then you just do as follows on the module that will use the Jama classes: Right-click the top node of the project:

[image]

Then choose "Properties" --> "Libraries" --> "Wrapped JARs" tab. And add your Jama jar there.